# Hazelcast Map: remove entries owned by the node that goes down

Tags: java, dictionary, hazelcast

I use IMap object to share some informations between the cluster nodes.
This informations is relevant to the node and are inserted by the same node in the shared map, so if the node is removed from the cluster does not make sense that there are.

I know that exists a MemberShipListener and I can capture the event memberRemoved but I don't know how I can remove the entries owned by the removed member. So I want to know if exists a method that can do it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way, at least not that I'm aware of, however you can build a small workaround. To do that you keep a second data structure (a MultiMap) to hold information about unique IDs of the members and their assigned keys. The following shows some pseudocode:

```
class MapWrapper<K, V> {
  MultiMap<String, K> metadata = hazelcastInstance.getMultiMap("metadata");

  Cluster cluster = hazelcastInstance.getCluster();
  Member localMember = cluster.getLocalMember();
  String uuid = localMember.getUuid();

  IMap<K, V> realMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("...");

  public void putWrapper(K key, V value) {
    realMap.put(key, value);
    metadata.put(uuid, key);
  }
}
```

You can use the MembershipListerner and first test if the current node is the "leader" (oldest member of the cluster) by asking the cluster about all members and take the first one of the result set.

```
Cluster cluster = hazelcastInstance.getCluster();
Member leader = cluster.getMembers().iterator().next();
if (cluster.getLocalMember().equals(leader)) { ... }
```

Now since you know this operation will only happen once (only on the leader) just use the metadata to remove elements like following:

```
void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
  if (isLeader()) {
    Member removedMember = membershipEvent.getMember();
    Collection<K> keys = metadata.remove(removedMember.getUuid());
    realMap.removeAll(keys);
  }
}
```

Probably not the nice solution you were looking for but so far I don't see another way to handle your use case. I'm looking forward to other solutions :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful. I also try if there are other solutions and let you know :)

Comment: I did not find other solutions. I tried if there is the possibility to do Hazelcast local map but without result. Do you know there is this possibility? Would it be an interesting feature to be included in Hazelcast? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always issue a feature request on github :-) Just link to this discussion and give a nice description of the idea / use case.